# Can I open the gui screen of an external file in a pop-up window on the main screen in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wonder about putting up a new Window Screen.
I have created two .py files

1. Main.py
2. popup.py

I imported popup.py into Main.py.

I want the popup.py window to turn on as a popup window when I click the button of SearchButton_2.

How do I change the code?

This file name is Main.py and is the First File.

```
import popup
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(991, 471)
        Dialog.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)

        font1 = QtGui.QFont()
        font1.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font1.setBold(True)
        font1.setWeight(75)
        
        self.ListTable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.ListTable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 991, 431))
        self.ListTable.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1191, 16777215))
        self.ListTable.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.ListTable.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.ListTable.setFont(font)
        self.ListTable.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.ListTable.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.ListTable.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.ListTable.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.ListTable.setAutoScroll(True)
        self.ListTable.setAutoScrollMargin(16)
        self.ListTable.setShowGrid(True)
        self.ListTable.setRowCount(0)
        self.ListTable.setColumnCount(5)
        self.ListTable.setObjectName("ListTable")
        self.ListTable.setColumnWidth(0,280)
        self.ListTable.setColumnWidth(1,190)
        self.ListTable.setColumnWidth(2,190)
        self.ListTable.setColumnWidth(3,190)
        self.ListTable.setColumnWidth(4,150)
        
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        
        self.SaveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.SaveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 40, 22))
        self.SaveButton.setObjectName("SaveButton")
                                                     
        self.SearchButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.SearchButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 60, 22))
        self.SearchButton_2.setObjectName("SearchButton_2")
        #self.SearchButton_2.clicked.connect()

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.ListTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["111","222","333","444","555"])
        self.SaveButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "save"))
        self.SearchButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "search"))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    Pialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This file name is popup.py and is the Second File.
popup.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Popup(object):
    def popup_ui(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(580, 100)
        self.SettingTime = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.SettingTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 61, 20))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(50)

        font1 = QtGui.QFont()
        font1.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font1.setPointSize(10)
        font1.setBold(True)
        font1.setWeight(75)

        self.StartTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(Dialog)
        self.StartTime.setFont(font)
        self.StartTime.setObjectName("SettingTime")
        self.StartTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 194, 22))
        self.StartTime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.StartTime.setObjectName("StartTime")

        self.SettingTime2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.SettingTime2.setFont(font)
        self.SettingTime2.setObjectName("SettingTime2")
        self.SettingTime2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 72, 16, 16))

        self.EndTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(Dialog)
        self.EndTime.setFont(font)
        self.EndTime.setObjectName("EndTime")
        self.EndTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 194, 22))
        self.EndTime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

        self.Category = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.Category.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 76, 22))
        self.Category.setObjectName("Category")
        self.Category.addItem("")
        self.Category.addItem("")
        self.Category.addItem("")
        self.Category.addItem("")
        self.Category.addItem("")
        self.Category.addItem("")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 321, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.Artifacts = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.Artifacts.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 76, 22))
        self.Artifacts.setObjectName("Artifacts")
        self.Artifacts.addItem("")
        self.Artifacts.addItem("")
        self.Artifacts.addItem("")
        self.Artifacts.addItem("")
        self.Artifacts.addItem("")

        self.SearchButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.SearchButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 10, 75, 22))
        self.SearchButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.SearchButton.setChecked(True)
        self.SearchButton.setObjectName("SearchButton")

        self.FileSize = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.FileSize.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 321, 21))
        self.FileSize.setObjectName("FileSize")

        self.SettingTime_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.SettingTime_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 91, 20))
        self.SettingTime_2.setFont(font)
        self.SettingTime_2.setObjectName("SettingTime_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.SettingTime.setText(_translate("Dialog", "111"))
        self.Category.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "222"))
        self.Category.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "333"))
        self.Category.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "444"))
        self.Category.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "555"))
        self.Category.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "666"))
        self.Category.setItemText(5, _translate("Dialog", "777"))
        self.SettingTime2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "~"))
        self.Artifacts.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "AAA"))
        self.Artifacts.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "BBB"))
        self.Artifacts.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "CCC"))
        self.Artifacts.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "DDD"))
        self.Artifacts.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "EEE"))
        self.SearchButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "FFF"))
        self.SettingTime_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "GGG"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Popup()
    ui.popup_ui(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have **not** changed the code in the first place. The files generated with `pyuic` should *always* be used as imported modules in your scripts, and should *never* be manually modified. Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

So, first of all, generate those files again. Then you must create a new script, which will be the "main" script of your program, and create your logic from there. The following examples implies that the files created again with pyuic are named `first.py` and `popup.py`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from first import Ui_Dialog
from popup import Popup

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.SearchButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showPopup)

    def showPopup(self):
        popup = PopupWindow(self)
        popup.exec_()


class PopupWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Popup):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I try confirm to method and try it.